# What will android system do when user taps outside a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog includes edittext, when user tabs the dialog and not on the keyboard or on the edittext, dialog will dismiss and so does softkeyboard, what does system deal with this action? It can dismiss the keyboard sometimes and others does not, I am confused about it. Thank you!

Comment: use dilaog property for setcancelable(true or false);

Comment: Thank you but I think maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to dismiss the soft keyboard manually if it still shows when dialog dismiss or any other system function call.

Comment: then use public void hideKeyboard() {
        Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

Comment: Where should I put this code ? Do you think call hideKeyboard() in dialog dismiss listener function ondismiss() is OK? mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {...?

Comment: yes, call that method anywhere and your keyboard hides

Comment: you should put this code when you click after enter some data in your edittext..

Comment: @Divyesh Thank you for your solution, in works on me on half cases, when user tap outside the dialog, dialog dismiss and it call ondismiss function ,but the keyboard still on, do you think keyboard can show on without any focus in the view?

Comment: Try to add softInputmode:statehidden inside of manifest activity tag

Comment: @Divyesh Thank you so much , I find the problem, other's code bring the keyboard showing again, your code totally works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Pleasure. Can you vote up my code so I post code as answer.

Comment: Sure can you tell me how to vote it, I am newer in this website.

Comment: I posted answer. now click up arrow to vote up and mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
public void hideKeyboard(){
Activity activity = (Activity) mContext; 
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus(); 
if (view != null) { 
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); 
} 
}
```

add 
`softInputmode:statehidden` inside of manifest activity tag

Comment: Divyesh, in my own code in a fragment when dialog dismiss the soft keyboard dismiss too, while some else use my fragment and the softkeybaord does not dismiss following dialog, do you know anything about this case? I try to find the reason.

Comment: did you put statehidden in every activity?

Comment: No, is it very important? I check that statehidden  is not to show soft keybaord.

Comment: try to add that in every activity and check if problem occurs or not